# How to remove the shadow of nav bar active

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navigation bar (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe6Rq.png) and want to remove the dark shadow leaving only blank letter when this active.

The site is: http://us.insidecraft.com/pruebas2/

Thank you.

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following lines to your custom css and it will do the trick!

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `background-color` value of this :

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

AND this :

```
.navbar-nav li.active {
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```